# Prevent long string spilling into adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a XLS created from Ms-access using automation.  I have some cells containing a LONG string of data. If the adjacent cell is NULL, then that long string spills into this adjacent cell.

I realize there are a couple brute force methods to address this:

1. Force-fill a " " char into the Null Cells
2. Wrap the long text, but constrain the row-height to a single row

I could swear there was a more elegant approach to this issue, but cannot recall.

Comment: To be clear: the string is not actually "spilling" in to the adjacent cells. The string is still fully contained within the cell where it resides. It is just the visual *appearance* you are concerned with?

Comment: You could always select "Shrink to fit" in the 'Alignment' section of the properties menu for the problem cell range. (CTRL + 1 as the hotkey to bring this up)

Comment: Thanks, yes this is just a visual thing.  Autofit is not a good option here as just a small number of cells have the LONG string; I don;t really want to accommodate the column width to these "offending" records (lots of columns for client review, trying to compact the display a bit).

Answer (score 0):

Option #2 is what I usually use:

```
Sub cell_alignment()
With ActiveCell
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
End With
End Sub
```

extra cleanup commands if needed and simplified wordwrap command:

```
activecell.WrapText = True
cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
```